# Optimizing the computation of rows using Pyspark

Tags: performance, pyspark, optimization, bigdata, computation

I'm encountering a problem that is working with loops in pandas is not efficient, and I'm new to Pyspark, so I would like to ask for ideas, solutions to complete 2 tasks illustrated below.

I have a dataset consisting of 700K rows like this:

Date format: MM-DD-YYYY

| ID | DATE | REF_DATE | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-31-2020 | 10-31-2019 | 3000 | 0.05 | 320 |
| 2 | 02-28-2020 | 10-31-2019 | 2750 | 0.04 | 300 |
| 3 | 03-31-2020 | 10-31-2019 | 2600 | 0.03 | 270 |

Tasks/steps:

**1. Generate new rows for each id if the condition is satisfied**

Condition: if Date > Ref_Date, add one more row, with the value of date decreasedcreased by 1 month unit until the new added date value = Ref_Date, keeping other variables' value constant.
This is the expected output which will have in reality 30 million rows.

| ID | DATE | REF_DATE | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-31-2020 | 10-31-2019 | 3000 | 0.05 | 320 |
| 1 | 12-31-2019 | 10-31-2019 | 3000 | 0.05 | 320 |
| 1 | 11-30-2019 | 10-31-2019 | 3000 | 0.05 | 320 |
| 1 | 10-31-2019 | 10-31-2019 | 3000 | 0.05 | 320 |
| 2 | 02-28-2020 | 10-31-2019 | 2750 | 0.04 | 300 |
| 2 | 01-31-2020 | 10-31-2019 | 2750 | 0.04 | 300 |
| 2 | 12-31-2019 | 10-31-2019 | 2750 | 0.04 | 300 |
| 2 | 11-30-2019 | 10-31-2019 | 2750 | 0.04 | 300 |
| 2 | 10-31-2019 | 10-31-2019 | 2750 | 0.04 | 300 |
| 3 | 03-31-2020 | 10-31-2019 | 2600 | 0.03 | 270 |
| 3 | 02-28-2020 | 10-31-2019 | 2600 | 0.03 | 270 |
| 3 | 01-31-2020 | 10-31-2019 | 2600 | 0.03 | 270 |
| 3 | 12-31-2019 | 10-31-2019 | 2600 | 0.03 | 270 |
| 3 | 11-30-2019 | 10-31-2019 | 2600 | 0.03 | 270 |
| 3 | 10-31-2019 | 10-31-2019 | 2600 | 0.03 | 270 |

**2. Create & compute 3 new columns named D, E, F as follows**

```
IF it's the first observation within the group (by ID):
    E = A * B
    F = C - E
    D = A - C 
IF it's the second and later on rows within that group:
    E = lag(D) * B
    F = C - E
    D = lag(D) - C
```

D here indicates the value of D from the previous row, if we proceed row 2, we use D from row 1, then to proceed row 3, we use the value of D of row 2, ...

The expected output will be like, I show only the first ID as an example, the other ID will be processed in the same manner.

| ID | DATE | REF_DATE | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-31-2020 | 10-31-2019 | 3000 | 0.05 | 320 | 2830 | 150 | 170 |
| 1 | 10-31-2019 | 10-31-2019 | 3000 | 0.05 | 320 | 2651.5 | 141.5 | 178.5 |
| 1 | 12-31-2019 | 10-31-2019 | 3000 | 0.05 | 320 | 2464.01 | 132.6 | 187.4 |
| 1 | 11-30-2019 | 10-31-2019 | 3000 | 0.05 | 320 | 2267.3 | 123.2 | 196.8 |

P.s: I need to process and store this whole dataset for other calculation later. Is there any way without using loops?
Thank you!

I tried using pandas and multithreading but now I need to do it in Pyspark

Comment: Can you explain the expected output? the given output seems incorrect according to your logic since for the firs row the value of E should be `3000 * 0.05=150`

Comment: Also the values of D in your expected output seems incorrect.

Comment: You are right that the output was in correct as I copied from excel and one line was missing. Thanks for pointing that out. I have just edited it